# Which T-SQL Skip Take Query Is Better?

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, pagination

**12/17/2015 - UPDATE**

It's been a while since I asked this question and haven't really gotten an answer so I thought I would post the solution that my team ended up using.

We originally started by using the dynamic SQL option to get the smart sorting.  While functional this felt really dirty.  We eventually came up with the following implementation:

```
--Params
DECLARE 
    @pageSize INT
    , @pageIndex INT
    , @sortBy varchar(30)
    , @sortDirection varchar(4);

SET @pageIndex = 1;
SET @pageSize = 10;
SET @sortBy = 'PolicyCode';
SET @sortDirection = 'ASC';

--Vars
DECLARE @start INT,
        @end INT;

--Page 1-n
SET @pageIndex = 1;
SET @pageSize = 10;

SET @start = (@pageSize * @pageIndex) - (@pageSize - 1);
SET @end = (@pageSize * @pageIndex);

;WITH PolicyCTE AS (
    SELECT p.PolicyId, p.PolicyTypeId, p.PolicyCode, p.PolicyDesc, p.EffectiveDate, p.ExpirationDate
    FROM Policy p INNER JOIN PolicyOrg po ON p.PolicyId = po.PolicyId
)
, PagedResultsCTE AS (
    SELECT
        [PolicyId]
        , [PolicyTypeId]
        , [PolicyCode]
        , [PolicyDesc]
        , [EffectiveDate]
        , [ExpirationDate]
        , CASE
            WHEN @sortBy = 'PolicyTypeId' AND @sortDirection = 'ASC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [PolicyTypeId] ASC)
            WHEN @sortBy = 'PolicyTypeId' AND @sortDirection = 'DESC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [PolicyTypeId] DESC)
            WHEN @sortBy = 'PolicyCode' AND @sortDirection = 'ASC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [PolicyCode])
            WHEN @sortBy = 'PolicyCode' AND @sortDirection = 'DESC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [PolicyCode] DESC)
            WHEN @sortBy = 'PolicyDesc' AND @sortDirection = 'ASC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [PolicyDesc])
            WHEN @sortBy = 'PolicyDesc' AND @sortDirection = 'DESC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [PolicyDesc] DESC)
            WHEN @sortBy = 'EffectiveDate' AND @sortDirection = 'ASC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [EffectiveDate])
            WHEN @sortBy = 'EffectiveDate' AND @sortDirection = 'DESC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [EffectiveDate] DESC)
            WHEN @sortBy = 'ExpirationDate' AND @sortDirection = 'ASC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [ExpirationDate])
            WHEN @sortBy = 'ExpirationDate' AND @sortDirection = 'DESC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [ExpirationDate] DESC)
        END AS RowNumber            
    FROM PolicyCTE
)
SELECT PolicyId, PolicyTypeId, PolicyCode, PolicyDesc, EffectiveDate, ExpirationDate
FROM PagedResultsCTE
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN @start AND @end
ORDER BY RowNumber

GO
```

By combining CASE statements and another CTE, we are able to sort by the passed in sorting criteria and also get the correct ROWNUMBER() value.  Then, in our final select statement, we can simply order by the rownumber column.

I'll avoid marking the question answered for now in case anyone wants to chime in on this solution.  Feedback is definitely welcome.

**ORIGINAL POST**

Maybe someone with a little more DBA knowledge can shed some light on this for me.  The basic premise: Get paginated data to improve page load performance (get records 1-10, 11-20, etc.) using an optimized query within a stored procedure.  The tables have thousands of records.

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and came up with the following T-SQL for use in a stored procedure:

```
--Params
DECLARE @pageSize INT,
        @pageIndex INT;

SET @pageIndex = 1;
SET @pageSize = 10;

--Vars
DECLARE @start INT,
        @end INT

--Page 1-n
SET @pageIndex = 1;
SET @pageSize = 10;

SET @start = (@pageSize * @pageIndex) - (@pageSize - 1);
SET @end = (@pageSize * @pageIndex)

;WITH PolicyCTE AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY p.PolicyCode) AS RowNumber, 
        p.PolicyId, p.PolicyTypeId, p.PolicyCode, p.PolicyDesc, p.EffectiveDate, p.ExpirationDate
    FROM Policy p INNER JOIN PolicyOrg po ON p.PolicyId = po.PolicyId
)
SELECT PolicyId, PolicyTypeId, PolicyCode, PolicyDesc, EffectiveDate, ExpirationDate
FROM PolicyCTE
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN @start AND @end
ORDER BY PolicyCode

GO
```

In my search to find best practices on how to do this, I ran into this **old** MSDN Patterns and Practices article: [How To: Page Records in .NET Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650700.aspx) (applies to SQL 2000 and states the article is out of date).  Referencing the **User-Specific Records** section, a somewhat equivalent T-SQL would look like this:

```
DECLARE
    @pageIndex int,
    @pageSize int,
    @sortBy nvarchar(30)

SET @pageIndex = 0;
SET @pageSize = 10;
SET @sortBy = 'PolicyCode';

DECLARE @rowsToRetrieve int,
        @sortDirFlipped nvarchar(4);

IF @pageIndex < 1 SET @pageIndex = 1;
IF @pageSize < 1 SET @pageSize = 10;

SET @rowsToRetrieve = @pageIndex * @pageSize

DECLARE @sqlString nvarchar(1000);
SET @sqlString = N'
    SELECT PolicyId, PolicyTypeId, PolicyCode, PolicyDesc, EffectiveDate, ExpirationDate
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP ' + CAST(@pageSize AS VARCHAR(10)) +  ' PolicyId, PolicyTypeId, PolicyCode, PolicyDesc, EffectiveDate, ExpirationDate
        FROM (
            SELECT TOP ' + CAST(@rowsToRetrieve AS VARCHAR(10)) +  ' PolicyId, PolicyTypeId, PolicyCode, PolicyDesc, EffectiveDate, ExpirationDate
            FROM (
                SELECT TOP ' + CAST(@rowsToRetrieve AS VARCHAR(10)) +  ' p.PolicyId, p.PolicyTypeId, p.PolicyCode, p.PolicyDesc, p.EffectiveDate, p.ExpirationDate
                FROM Policy p INNER JOIN PolicyOrg po ON p.PolicyId = po.PolicyId
                ORDER BY p.' + @sortBy + '
            ) AS T2
            ORDER BY ' + @sortBy + ' DESC
        ) AS T3
    ) AS T4
    ORDER BY ' + @sortBy + ' ASC';

EXEC(@sqlString)
GO
```

I've run both of these with Execution Plan and Client Statistics on and it seems to me (definitely not an expert in analyzing those results) that the MSDN version performs better.  Part of the reason, from what I can gather, is that the MSDN version starts out with a smaller record set.  However, I really dislike the fact that the MSDN version uses a dynamic query.  My understanding is that they are more vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Most of the examples I found prefer the form of the first sample.  Can someone help explain this to me and site reasons why, besides the ones already listed, the first form would be better than the second?

Comment: Dynamic SQL is vulnerable when exposed outside something like a stored procedure.  The MSDN example can be convert if you have a static sort.  I would also look at the ROW_NUMBER function.

Comment: The former is definitely better and will be cacheable by the query optimizer, but the dynamic SQL might be a bit smarter about how it does its query. Have you looked into [Offset and Fetch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618.aspx) in SQL Server? If you're running SQL Server 2012, it'll be much faster than either option.

Comment: @AaronFriel, I have looked into that but unfortunately I am not running SQL Server 2012.  I guess it depends on whether I want it to be cacheable vs. smarter.

Comment: @ChrisH That's a good point about the dynamic SQL.  By the way, my first example uses ROW_NUMBER.